# DB backup script - Call to undefined function error - due to if statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

**The error**

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function `backup_tables()`

**The code:**

```
<?php
$doBackupDB=$_REQUEST["doBackupDB"];
if($doBackupDB=='yes')
{

// create new fresh backup
// dont forget to give it hotname, username, password and db requirements in line below
backup_tables($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);
/* backup the db OR just a table */
// call db variables from your db
function backup_tables($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname,$tables = '*')
{

$link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);

//get all of the tables
if($tables == '*')
{
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$tables[] = $row[0];
}
}
else
{
$tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
}

//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

$return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
$return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
{
$row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
}
$return.= ");\n";
}
}
$return.="\n\n\n";
}
//save file
$handle = fopen('backups/db-backup-'.time().'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);

}


}
?>
```

**The Confusion/Problem**

Now I know it's happening because of this if statement:

```
$doBackupDB=$_REQUEST["doBackupDB"];
if($doBackupDB=='yes')
{
// backup code 
}
```

Basically I want to trigger this backup by clicking a button, like this:

```
backup.php?doBackupDB=yes
```

If I don't use this if statement, backup is being created on page load, because the script executes automatically.

If i try to control it and use an if statement to check that if button was clicked and the page reloads and the variable was passed to `dobackup` then script should run --- here the error occurs.

Please advise. For now, I have to empty the backup directory before backup script runs, on page load, to get the fresh backup by this script and to delete old.

Comment: Using the antiquated, deprecated `mysql_query` functions is dangerous enough. Using them to make backups is outrageous.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Which query is deprecated in above code? Are you pointing towards mysql to > mysqli ? Or there are more?

Comment: PDO is the most modern interface, and `mysqli` is a decent alternative if you can't use PDO for whatever reason. `mysql_query` is being phased out and will be removed entirely in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your `backup_tables` function inside your `if`. Is that really what you wanted? I would move the function definition out of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please **DO NOT** do this. What you've got here is no different from what [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) can already do, and secondly, your [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) with `addslashes` is woefully ineffective and will lead to corrupted backups. Rolling your own backup tool is **extremely dangerous** and should be undertaken as an absolute last resort.

**DO** use `mysqldump` to create consistent database snapshots. You can initiate this process from within PHP if desired.

Comment: Thank you. I tried by using this code:

<?php
$backupFile = "backups/db_name-".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".sql";
$command = "mysqldump –u[root] –p[] [db_name] > $backupFile";
system($command);
?>

but it is dumping empty sql file.

Comment: Can anyone rewrite the script with using mysqli (not just a row or two but post the whole thing)?
Or can anyone write the mysqldump way script to download full db backup?

Comment: You should check that the command you're composing works correctly. You can test this by printing it out before executing it, and trying that on the command-line separately. You may have an error with your username or password specification. `[db_name]` should be `db_name`, whatever that is. Square brackets are usually used to indicate placeholders in documentation and are not intended to be used literally.

Comment: I have tried various variations of that code but it gives me empty sql file. I am using wamp localserver with no password for phpmyadmin so i have to leave the password field blank in it 'mysqldump -–uroot –-p db_name > $backupFile' 'mysqldump -user root -password= db_name > $backupFile' and more but only empty sql file is being generated